# How to develop OSGi bundles without opening or importing the dependent bundles in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

I am currently facing a problem where eclipse is not able to resolve a plugin dependency specified in the manifest.

Let me generalize my problem with the help of 2 plugins.
Say one plugin is a core plugin “com.mycompany.core”, and the other is a fancy plugin  “com.mycompany.fancy”.

The plugin com.mycompany.core is a plugin owned by a different team and is deployed in my company’s maven repository, under the group id “com.example”

My team owns com.mycompany.fancy. This plugin has a dependency to the plugin “com.mycompany.core”.

For simplicity sake let me call these plugins “fancy” and “core” respectively.

We would like to work with only the “fancy” plugin in the eclipse IDE.

I am currently building the “fancy" plugin using tycho. The pom file of the fancy plugin has an explicit dependency to “core” plugin in its dependencies section.
I generate the .classpath and the .project for the “fancy” plugin using 
**Mvn eclipse:eclipse**

After importing the generated project for the fancy plugin in eclipse IDE, I see that eclipse is not able to resolve the dependency to the “core” plugin that is specified in its Manifest file. Eclipse reports an error saying **“Bundle ‘com.mycompany.core’ cannot be resolved.**
Under the referenced libraries of the “fancy” project, I see that eclipse lists  the “core” plugin. The location of the core plugin jar is C:\mvn_repo\com\example\com.mycompany.core\1.0.0\com.mycompany.core-1.0.0.jar
This is the location where the “Core” plugin jar is deployed in maven, and this location is a valid location on my machine.

I also see that the generated .classpath file for “fancy” has the following entry

However, eclipse is not able to resolve the dependency entry for the plugin “Core” in the manifest of “Fancy”.

From command line, there are no issues seen. However, the fact that there are errors in eclipse, means that we cannot launch/run anything from within eclipse, which is a show stopper for us.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem, or what it would take for eclipse to recognize the bundle that has been specified with its location in the .classpath file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a [Target Platform](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) that can be used by both the Tycho build and in your IDE workspaces. Eclipse's default behavior for bundle/plug-in development is to use the running IDE as the Target Platform, but that's an unfortunate default because it's a very bad idea for almost any "real" project. Instead you should use a specific TP in which you dictate exactly what dependencies you have, and [use that same target definition in Tycho, too](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform).

Comment: Hi E-Riz- Thanks for your reply. This approach worked for me. Editing the target platform to contain the directories that would contain the plugins that my workspace plugins are dependent on did the trick. The following link helped as well. http://eclipse-debug.blogspot.com/2010/09/what-is-target-platform.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the maven scope setting when you declare the bundle depency.  Offhand I think you're looking forRUNTIME.